Are questions about iOS permissions allowed if they're related to programming?
The question in question: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/36516901
It doesn't have any code and only uses Apple's permission stuff.
Although I believe this question is off-topic for other reasons (not focused, etc.), it raises another question.
Are questions about Apple's permission stuff allowed because it's a tool that programmers use?

The question that I think that is pertinent is: are IOS permission settings often used for non-programming purposes?

It's been a while since I did mobile apps devt, but part of app dev't is defining your app configs, which includes permissions, and how it will interact with the system permissions when your app runs. It's not just a "tool". It's usually required to define it properly when bundling your app, and your app runtime also depends on it. The question mentions NSNearbyInteractionUsageDescription. I think the issue with that question is more about missing debugging details.

[tag:ios-permissions] and its sibling [tag:android-permissions]

"It doesn't have any code and only uses Apple's permission stuff.". I checked the link and I saw what definitely looks like code (starting with func startupMPC()), although the programming language wasn't identified.

@KarlKnechtel Revision 1 had no code. Revision 2 came after the Triage rejection

I'm inclined to think the same rules for Apple Store questions apply here: questions about code are on-topic. Questions about changes Apple has made to their OS are not. Revision 1 seems to be the latter. Revision 2 seems to be the former.
